# safest way to parse a string and split it

Tags: c#

I have a string that's like that:

```
UNIQUE_ID-String-TriggerID
82-DEFAULT-4;MINIMODE_ARCADE-1;MINIMODE_RUNNER-4;47-STARLING-1;
```

Some Input Examples:

```
1) 82-Mode1-4;
2) 4-Arcade-2;9-Runner-2;90-STARLING-1;  // here you see Unique ID 4 has two entries 
3) 82-DEFAULT-4;MINIMODE_ARCADE-1;MINIMODE_RUNNER-4;47-STARLING-1; 2-DEFAULT-4;MINIMODE_ARCADE-0; 
// here 82 UNIQUE ID and 2 UNIQUE ID has two enteritis, but 47 UNIQUE ID has just one enterey
```

The problem is sometimes I get only one entry for the UniqueID 47, and sometimes I get for ID 82 multiple entries.

How would I split and parse the string correctly?

I'm putting the parsed string in a dictionary, so sometimes I get the same key to be added and that raises an exception

I have done the following but still can't trace all situations:

```
        String data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(Progress));

        String[] progressEntries = data.Split(';');

        for (int i = 0; i < progressEntries.Length; i++)
        {
            String entry = progressEntries[i];
            String[] values = entry.Split('-');

            if (values.Length > 2)
            {
                Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                dict[values[1]] = Convert.ToInt32(values[2]);
                Progress.Add(Convert.ToInt32(values[0]), dict);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some additional examples of the input and expected output.

Comment: If keys may repeat, you have to use another collection. Something like List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>

Comment: Maybe you should explain that parsing a bit better. Not just "has two entries", but *which two*. Now the comments and the examples do not seem to match.

Comment: In your sample code you are creating fresh dictionaries that will not throw that exception. Probably the exception occurs in `Progress.Add`. Can we see that code? (or point to the line where that exception really occurs)

Comment: yea it points to Progress.Add the exception.

Comment: @HansKesting the two entries, are the two that are following the UNIQUE_ID.  Sometimes, following the UNIQUE_ID there is only entry that is ended by ; or two entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not too clear but let's give it a try.
In the text you provided:

```
82-DEFAULT-4;MINIMODE_ARCADE-1;MINIMODE_RUNNER-4;47-STARLING-1;
```

you have **two groups**. Each group has key-value pairs

- group 1 - key: 82

  - DEFAULT: 4
  - MINIMODE_ARCADE: 1
  - MINIMODE_RUNNER: 4
- group 2 - key: 47

  - STARLING: 1

If this is the structure you want to obtain then one storage possibility would be a `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<string,int>>`

I think the following code will do:

```
public class Parser
{
    public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> Parse(string input)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> data = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>>();

        int? currentGroupKey = null;
        string[] keyValuePairs = input.Split(new char[] { ';' });
        foreach (var kvp in keyValuePairs)
        {
            string[] tokens = kvp.Split(new char[] { '-' });
            switch (tokens.Length)
            {
                case 2:
                    {
                        if (currentGroupKey.HasValue)
                        {
                            int groupKey = currentGroupKey.Value;
                            AddKeyValuePair(data, groupKey, tokens[0], tokens[1]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        int groupKey;
                        if (int.TryParse(tokens[0], out groupKey))
                        {
                            currentGroupKey = groupKey;
                            AddKeyValuePair(data, groupKey, tokens[1], tokens[2]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
        return data;
    }

    private void AddKeyValuePair(Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> data, int groupKey, string key, string val)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> group;
        if (data.ContainsKey(groupKey))
        {
            group = data[groupKey];
        }
        else
        {
            group = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            data[groupKey] = group;
        }

        int intVal;
        if (int.TryParse(val, out intVal))
            group.Add(key, intVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Next time try to visualize data and to better explain your problem. Oh wait... Then you will be able to solve the problem by yourself!

Comment: @B-Andrew, stress and inexperience in c# collections :(